# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{\frac{i}{n^{3}}}$ using Riemann Sums and FTC

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Factoring out the $\frac {1}{n}$ out of the sigma, we get:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{\frac{i}{n}}\cdot\frac{1}{n}$$
which looks awfully similar to 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{x^{*}_i}\cdot\Delta{x}$$
$f(x) = \sqrt{x}$

$\Delta{x} = \frac{a - b}{n} = \frac{1}{n}$

So, I simply evaluate
$$\int^{b}_{a} \sqrt{x}\cdot dx$$
with $b = 1$ and $a = 0$ and get the answer $\frac{2}{3}$. But... why? Why is $b = 1$ and why is $a = 0$?

Comment: What is the maximum value of $i/n$?  What is the minimum?  What are the limits of those two values as $n \to \infty$?  What relationship does $i/n$ have with $x_i$, given $n$?

Comment: Oh, that makes much more sense now. The maximum value of $x^*_i$ is $\frac{n}{n}$, which is 1. The minimum, on the other hand, is $\frac{0}{n}$, which is 0. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding the Riemann Sum:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\frac in}\frac1n
&=\sum_{i=1}^nf\left(\frac in\right)\frac1n\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^nf\left(x_i\right)(x_i-x_{i-1})\\
&\to\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^1\sqrt{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\[6pt]
&=\frac{2}{3}
\end{align}
$$
Since $x_i=\frac in$, $x_i$ ranges from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be $\frac{2}{3}$?

Comment: @ChrisK: Yes, but I was on my mobile phone, and I couldn't get to edit since there was a suggested edit pending. Thanks for fixing that.

Comment: That's understandable.

Answer (score 1):

It is $b=1$ and $a=0$  because $ \{1/n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ is partition of $[0,1]$. Look that in your notation $\Delta x =\frac{b-a}{n} = \frac{1-0}{n} $.